# Multiple lines using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently trying to get everything between

`<p><strong>http://website2.website.com/</strong><br />`

and

`<p><strong>`

```html
</strong></p>
<p><strong>http://website2.website.com/</strong><br />
<strong>1234123:12rwe</strong><br />
<strong>ewqwe:rjbvm225</strong><br />
<strong>mel35:zzrg</strong><br />
<p><strong>
```

This is what I have so far

```
MatchCollection RealMe = Regex.Matches(html, @"website2(.*)<p><strong>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            foreach (Match combo in RealMe)
            {
                if (!combot.Value.Contains("xhtml"))
                {
                    listboxRealMe.Items.Add(combo);
                }
            }
```

**This issue with this is that the `listboxRealMe` adds everything into one line, instead of creating a new item for each line**

Comment: Why don't you just use [CSQuery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery) for this? It'll be much more robust.

Comment: Does `website2(.*?)<p><strong>` improve the situation?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski never heard of CSQuery, I'm checking it out right now

Comment: Ok so by what you are saying, _one_ match is everything in the middle there. So you took your _one_ match and added it as _one_ listbox item. A multi-line textbox probably shows them on different lines. A listbox I would expect to see render each item you add on a line regardless of new line characters.

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks for that! It let me get exactly in between what I was looking for, but it still gets added onto the listbox as 1 item

Comment: @pshyoulost Did you try using `listboxRealMe.Items.Add(combo.Groups[1].Value);`? I guess you need just the captured part. I have just tested: all matches are correctly added to separate lines in a listbox, even if I just use `.Add(combo)`.

Comment: @pshyoulost: Will `listboxRealMe.Items.AddRange(combo.Value.Split(new string[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));` do what you want?

Comment: @stribizhev neither one of those worked :O

Comment: Then please provide more code. Is it a regular listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\.com/</strong><br />(.*)<p><strong>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline).Value;
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Regex Explanation:

```
\.com/</strong><br />(.*)<p><strong>

Options: Case insensitive; Exact spacing; Dot matches line breaks; ^$ match at line breaks; Numbered capture

Match the character “.” literally «\.»
Match the character string “com/</strong><br />” literally «com/</strong><br />»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*)»
   Match any single character «.*»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
Match the character string “<p><strong>” literally «<p><strong>»
```